# Rudin: Prove that if $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_nx^n$ converges for $|x|<R$, then $f'(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}nc_nx^{n-1}$ in $(-R, R)$.

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series, uniform-convergence

**The Problem**: If $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_nx^n$ converges for $|x|<R$, then $f'(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}nc_nx^{n-1}$ in $(-R, R)$.

The problem is a theorem from Walter Rudin's PMA:
[image]

Here is part of Rudin's proof:
[image]

**My Question**: I don't quite follow the texts highlighted in yellow. The Root Test-which I suppose is what he is applying here-says that:

[image]

Thus, (3) converges implies only that $\underset{n\to\infty}{\lim}\sup\sqrt[n]{\vert c_nx^n\vert}\leq1$ by (b) of Theorem 3.33, from which we at most can deduce that $\underset{n\to\infty}{\lim}\sup\sqrt[n]{|n c_n x^{n-1}|}\leq 1$ (because we have $\underset{n\to\infty}{\lim}\sup\sqrt[n]{n\vert c_n\vert}=\underset{n\to\infty}{\lim}\sup\sqrt[n]{\vert c_n\vert}$, thus it seems $\underset{n\to\infty}{\lim}\sup\sqrt[n]{\vert c_nx^n\vert}=\underset{n\to\infty}{\lim}\sup\sqrt[n]{|n c_n x^{n-1}|}$). But what happens if $\underset{n\to\infty}{\lim}\sup\sqrt[n]{|n c_n x^{n-1}|}=1$? The same conundrum exists when (3) diverges.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Oh boy...I got the definitions of $limsup$ completely wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking at the root test in the wrong way. Instead of Theorem 3.3, you should take a look at Theorem 3.39 in Rudin, which tells you that the radius of convergence is determined by the limsup of the absolute value of the coefficients. Therefore, the identity
$$
\limsup \sqrt[n]{n|c_n|}=\limsup \sqrt[n]{|c_n|}
$$
tells you that the (3) converges if and only if (5) converges. Note that $R$ in the theorem you quote could be *any* number not bigger than the radius of convergence (the $R$ in Theorem 3.39).

> [image]

Comment: This is the best advice.  When it comes to power series *forget about the root "test."*  Save that for other kind of series.  Just learn this Theorem 3.39.  (i) Every power series has a radius of convergence $R$, (ii) there is an exact formula for $R$, (iii)  this $R$ tells you about absolute convergence in $(-R,R)$, (iv) it tells you nothing about $x=R$ or $x=-R$ when $R$ is finite and positive.  (v) it tells you there is [dramatic] divergence if $x>R$ or $x<-R$ when $R$ is finite (vi) it even tells you about uniform convergence [but that is another tale].

Answer (score 1):

Observe the radius of convergence is defined as $R = \dfrac{1}{\limsup (|c_n|^{1/n})}$ so if you take $x \in (-R,R)$, you will have $\left|x \times {\limsup (|c_n|^{1/n})}\right|  < 1$, now ...